# gstreamer appsink can not get flvmux data

Tags: python, gstreamer

I use the gstreamer and python-gi to get encoded video stream data. My launch is like `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! x264enc bitrate=1000 ! h264parse ! flvmux ! appsink`.
Now I code in python like:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstApp', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstApp
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mainloop = GObject.MainLoop()
        self.pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()
        self.bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        self.bus.add_signal_watch()
        self.bus.connect('message::eos', self.on_eos)
        self.bus.connect('message::error', self.on_error)
        # Create elements
        self.src = Gst.ElementFactory.make('v4l2src', None)
        self.encoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make('x264enc', None)
        self.parse = Gst.ElementFactory.make('h264parse', None)
        self.mux = Gst.ElementFactory.make('flvmux', None)
        self.sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('appsink', None)
        # Add elements to pipeline
        self.pipeline.add(self.src)
        self.pipeline.add(self.encoder)
        self.pipeline.add(self.parse)
        self.pipeline.add(self.mux)
        self.pipeline.add(self.sink)
        # Set properties
        self.src.set_property('device', "/dev/video0")
        # Link elements
        self.src.link(self.encoder)
        self.encoder.link(self.parse)
        self.parse.link(self.mux)
        self.mux.link(self.sink)
    def run(self):
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        # self.mainloop.run()
        appsink_sample = GstApp.AppSink.pull_sample(self.sink)
        while True:
            buff = appsink_sample.get_buffer()
            size, offset, maxsize = buff.get_sizes()
            frame_data = buff.extract_dup(offset, size)
            print(frame_data)
    def kill(self):
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        self.mainloop.quit()
    def on_eos(self, bus, msg):
        print('on_eos()')
        self.kill()
    def on_error(self, bus, msg):
        print('on_error():', msg.parse_error())
        self.kill()
example = Example()
example.run()
```

But I got the same data for every time, just like "FLV\0x01\0x01".

And than I use C languare to code the function, but I got the same result. Why? Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gstreamer's process. We should use signal function to get the stream data in appsink.

Answer (score 0):

`print` prints strings I assume? The buffer contains binary data. It just starts with data that resembles a string. So probably it starts with FLV\0x01\0x01\0x00.. followed by more binary data. String functions will treat 0x00 as the end marker of a string and will stop printing (as the print function does not take a size argument this is the agreement where your data ends). The size property should change though.. unless all the data has the same data chunk size.. but you need to find another function that prints your binary data - although I'm not sure if that is really what you want. Maybe you want to write this data to a file instead?